# XML parsing error on file /WEB-INF/web.xml

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, maven

I am following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code) of Google App Engine for JAVA. I have successfully set up the project. When I run the server on my local machine by typing `mvn appengine:devserver` in the terminal, I get the following warning:

> [INFO] WARNING: Your working directory, (/home/xyz/workspace/appengine/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT) is not equal to your 
>   web application root (/home/xyz/workspace/appengine/guestbook/guestbook-ear/target/guestbook-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/guestbook-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war)
>   You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.

After that I receive the message :

> INFO: Dev App Server is now running

Now when I try to run the webpage by typing `http://localhost:8080/` in my browser, I get the following message:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> XML parsing error on file /WEB-INF/web.xml
>   Caused by:
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: XML parsing error on file /WEB-INF/web.xml
>   ...
>
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching: http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd
>   ...
>
> Caused by:
>
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching: http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd
>   ...

What should be done?

Comment: Seems like the DTD for some of your xml files cannot be retrieved ... possibly the server is down, or your network connection. You can probably remove the reference to the DTD from the xml file, since validation is usually optional.

Comment: Yes. This did the work.